# How to draw JButton infront of java graphics?

Tags: java, swing, draw, paintcomponent, jcomponent

I have a custom `JPanel` class which I add to my `Frame` and constantly update. This class has an overidden `paintComponent` and a `JButton`. How do I draw the `JButton` over my graphics drawn in my `paintComponent`? I constantly update this `paintCompoment` through a loop which `repaint()`'s it, But I do not change the `JButton`. My custom `JPanel` class is a subclass of my `Main` class.

My Panel Class

```
public class interTower extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    public interTower(){
        setVisible(true);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT));

        JButton interTower_back = new JButton("Back");
        interTower_back.setActionCommand("interTower_back");
        interTower_back.addActionListener(this);
        add(interTower_back);
    }

    @Override

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        drawMaster(g2d);
        g2d.dispose();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Move the `super.paintComponent(g);` to be the first line in the method.. 2) `g.dispose();` don't dispose of a `Graphics` object you did not create. 3) The `g2d` is the same graphics object. Don't dispose of it either. 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 4) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: *"Was already like that."* show an MCVE of code that is ***actually failing*** rather than posting 'something like' the code being used.

Comment: @AndrewThompson This piece of code is failing

Comment: *"This piece of code is failing"* Well, duh.. But that piece of code is an uncompilable code snippet, not an MCVE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Moved the super call and got rid of the dispose call for the unused graphics object

Answer (score 1):

By following AndrewThompsons wise words, I have fixed my issue! Disposing the graphics object seems to stop the rendering of the button. Removing the dispose call off of both of the object seems to of fixed my issue. Thanks AndrewThompson.